# How to create an editable UITableView like that of the Contacts app? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm looking for a way to develop a view like shown below. What is the easiest way to do this? Should I just create a whole bunch of different custom UITableViewCell's or is there some sort of framework I can use?

More specifically I'm wondering how to create the individual editable cells e.g. the cell with 'mobile (408) 555-5555'; how would I create this and allow users to edit it? If I also wanted to create a cell that allows users to select several checkable options how could I do this? Another case could be the use of a toggle switch in the cell.

**NOTE:** I'm not intending to develop a settings view, its for other purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my new favourite thing, static tableviews in storyboard.

In the storyboard editor, create a new table view controller and set the content type to static. Set the number of sections, drag in your cells and configure, set up some outlets - done!

You need to remove all of the datasource methods from the view controller for this to work. Yes, you read that right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this nice form view that I found. Its easy to use. 
https://github.com/redant-mobile/raformview