# iOS form controls

Tags: iphone, ios, forms, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create an editable UITableView like that of the Contacts app? (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864172/how-to-create-an-editable-uitableview-like-that-of-the-contacts-app-iphone)

I have been trying to create a form that looks similar to the iOS contacts app, where each row has a field name on the left and entry field on the right. Is this not a built in control for iOS? If not, how is it actually done?

Thank you.

Comment: [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/) with default/custom UITableViewCell

Comment: agreed, but as a beginner I find this post to be slightly more useful because of the more detailed explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by putting your text field within a `UITableViewCell` of an `UITableView`.

Then change the style of the cell upon initiation to:

```
cell.style = UITableViewCellStyleValue2;
```

> UITableViewCellStyleValue2 A style for a cell with a label on the left
>   side of the cell with text that is right-aligned and blue; on the
>   right side of the cell is another label with smaller text that is
>   left-aligned and black. The Phone/Contacts application uses cells in
>   this style. Available in iOS 3.0 and later. Declared in
>   UITableViewCell.h.
>   [Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You may do the same thing directly in Interface Builder by changing style to "Left Detail":

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: but can you edit the detail field?I think you can't edit it.

Comment: No, you cannot edit it, but you can add a `UITextField` within the `UITableViewCell`. You may do that like this: `[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];`

Answer (score 4):

It's not a built in control for ios.if you want to create this you can create a table view with custom cell in which you can put UILabel on the left side of the cell and put UITextField on the right side of the cell for editing.

Comment: if still you are facing the problem how to solve it see this link...http://kshitizghimire.com.np/create-custom-uitableviewcell/.this is just an sample not the accurate one as contacts app,but you can adjust it according to you requirment.